# Aspera P2P Inquiry

Tags: ssh, server, file-transfer, openssh, data-transfer

I have an ancient Aspera P2P 2.7.5 at work running on Windows 2008 box that recently died.  Please note this is an off the internet machine so I have no way to post screenshots.  When I migrate Aspera to Windows 2022 box, the built in SSH server side doesn't work.  So I used Windows 2022 built-in OpenSSH server.  Aspera is able to connect to itself using IBM suggestion for adding to sshd-config

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

However, when I do test transfer on the same box, I'm not able to transfer.  I keep getting SSH client connection error.  IBM showed us how to correct on Server side but how do I correct client side so it knows it needs to use diffie-hellman ?  Note, I can manually connect using W2022 OpenSSH Client with diffie-hellman extension.  So I think Aspera SSH client needs to know the extension.  IBM never shows us how to configure client side.  Any suggestion on how to address Aspera SSH client side?

Does anybody knows where can I download Aspera for free so I can test it offline?